# Web app: code from the ground up or use 3rd party framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm about to develop a web app (PHP/MySQL). I prefer to use the MVC style when developing apps, but I've always struggled writing my own MVC framework in the past so I've started playing with CodeIgniter. After a couple of tutorials I better understand how to properly develop with a MVC framework and I'm totally comfortable using CodeIgniter to write my app.

The thing is I'm now wondering if its better to write my own MVC framework for this app or use CodeIgniter? My worries are due to the fact that I'm just getting this app written to serve as a prototype and will hand it off to more experienced developers down the road. I'm worried CodeIgniter has limitations that I'm unaware of yet and could hinder further development for me or the next developer(s). I'd imagine its easier to get around issues/limitations of a custom framework than it is of a 3rd party/ready made/stock framework.

Any insight?

Comment: Is this subjective? I'm not sure. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any real limitations to CodeIgniter as most of the core can be extended. I have been using it for years and not found anything I couldn't use it for.

Kohana is a little more fun if you're into PHP5/OOP stuff but the lack of documentation will make learning it quickly rather difficult, especially if you are being paid to produce this.

Use CI, it will speed you up plenty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd would go with CodeIgniter if you're familiar with it (and not writing your own framework from scratch), the app is a prototype, and it's getting handed off to more experienced developers down the line.

CodeIgniter isn't an obscure framework, it's pretty widely used and well documented. If your developers kick up a fuss, then they're probably aren't as experienced as they would like to think they are.

Answer (score 1):

For a prototype I would say definitely use whatever you're familiar with, instead of making the project much bigger than it needs to be. Writing your own framework is a huge challenge, but it's also a really good learning experience. I've written my own suited to my own needs just so that I could learn the language "in the deep end" (and I keep adding to it whenever I use it... maybe someday, when I decide it's "fully featured", I'll release it into the wider world). But you should only do that if you've got the time, and plenty of room for everything to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is: can you do better than every other MVC PHP framework out there? Reinventing the wheel only costs more time and the focus off your application changes, because you have 2 seperate things to maintain.

I would stick with a proper MVC framework. We use [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) exclusively for that use. It's a great framework with a lot of features borrowed from other frameworks and other programming languages. However, the list is endlessly for PHP framework. I recommend reading a bit about other frameworks and pick the one which is the most suitable for your needs. It saves you time in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, I had to go through the same road.

Personally, I chose CodeIgniter as primary tool of my development, mainly because of community support and straightforward MVC. However, CodeIgniter was built by EllisLab, and they are not community driven. If you are looking for something that has more dynamic, community driven, open source MVC framework, I would suggest using Kohana.

Kohana has a good community, and they have some notable contributors. [Check it out here](http://kohanaframework.org/)

If you are thinking of choosing from different types of frameworks, I would suggest make a list of things you want out of a framework, and do your search based on that.